# read multiple csv file in python

Tags: python, file

I'm new in Python i have 10 csv file

```
f1.csv
55.4
67.4
23.56
12.5

f2.csv
9.5
26.1
6.2

.... 
f10.csv
3.2
9.45
3.91
3.8
```

I want to read these 10 files and then sum the value in each file, 
**the output**

```
sumf1=158.86
sumf2= 41.8
...
sumf10=20.36
```

this is my code to read and sum the data of one file, but I do not know how can read 10 files and then sum the values of each one, any help please?

```
  total = 0

with open('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\pys\\file1.csv', 'r') as inp:
    for line in inp:
        try:
            num = float(line)
            total += num
        except ValueError:
            print('{} is not a number!'.format(line))
    print('Total of all numbers: {}'.format(total))
```

Comment: Outsource the code into a function and loop over an array / list that contains the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have asked for it, no more and no less:

```
from glob import iglob

file_spec = '/some_path/*.csv' # to read all csv files
# file_spec = '/some_path/f*.csv' # to read all csv files for file names beginning with 'f'
# file_spec = '/some_path/*' # to read all files

for file in iglob(file_spec):
    sum = 0.0
    n = 0 # number of terms going into the sum
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                sum += float(line)
            except ValueError:
                print('Bad value: ', line, end='')
            else:
                n += 1
    mean = (sum / n) if n != 0 else "undefined"
    print(f'sum, mean for {file} => {sum}, {mean}')
```

Comment: Think of `f'/some_path/f{i}.csv'` as a regular file specification with `{i}` being replaced with 1, 2, 3, etc. successively each time through the loop. The `f` string literal requires Python3.

Comment: Yes , thanks for your helping, now I am asking if any way to read N file in folder

Comment: I don't understand your last comment/question.

Comment: Instead of 10 files, how can I read all the files in the folder (N files)?

Comment: With arbitrary names or f1.csv, f2,csv, ... fn.csv?

Comment: something like this f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f21,f22,f23,f24,f25,fnn1,fn2,fn3,fn4,fn5.

Comment: I have updated my answer **AGAIN**. You can specify whatever file pattern you want. Right now I have it to process any csv file.

Comment: sorry, now Iam try to compute mean to each one and use this                                             mean = sum/len(open('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/folder/f*.csv').readlines())  but I have this error OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/hp/Desktop/folder/f*.csv'

Comment: I think it is easier just to add a couple of lines to the existing code. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
def sumFile(filename):
    total = 0

    with open(filename, 'r') as inp:
        for line in inp:
            try:
                num = float(line)
                total += num
            except ValueError:
                print('{} is not a number!'.format(line))
        print('Total of all numbers: {}'.format(total))

    return total

total = sum(sumFile(filename) for filename in ["file1", "file2", "file3", "fileN"])
```

Comment: Ok, but I have 10 files !

Comment: @oleva: Just put all your filenames in the array.

Comment: Please, is there a way to read all the files in a folder?this method is more practical for me

Comment: @oleva: Yup - look into `glob()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a list of the files. Your code just needs an outer for loop:

```py
files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file4.csv'] # and so on

total = 0

for file in files:

    with open('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\pys\\{}'.format(file), 'r') as inp:
        for line in inp:
            try:
                num = float(line)
                total += num
            except ValueError:
                print('{} is not a number!'.format(line))

print('Total of all numbers: {}'.format(total))
```

If you would like to get all the files in one directory you could do this:

```py
from os import listdir

files = listdir('path_to_your_directory')

# Remove all the files that does not end with .csv
files = [file in files if file.endswith('.csv')]
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I have 10 or more csv file in folder how can read all these file, I put 10 file just for example

Comment: I have added with an example where you can read all the files in your directory